# Flutter Widget Test: StreamBuilder snapshot has connectionState = waiting with a non-empty Stream

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to write a widget test for a widget that uses `StreamBuilder`. In the builder, I return a `CircularProgressIndicator` if `snapshot.hasData` is `false`, otherwise I return a `ListView` of widgets.

In my test I create a `StreamController` and add an element to it. When I run the test, I would expect to see `snapshot.hasData` = `true`, but instead it's `false` and I can see that the `connectionState` is `waiting`. So my test fails.

Somehow it seems that the first element is not pulled out of the stream, and the connection remains in `waiting` state. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my widget test:

```
testWidgets('Job item pressed - shows edit job page',
  (WidgetTester tester) async {
StreamController<List<Job>> controller =
    StreamController<List<Job>>.broadcast(sync: true);

Job job = Job(id: '0', createdAt: 0, jobName: 'Dart');
controller.add([job]);

final page = JobsPage(
  jobsStream: controller.stream,
);
MockRouter mockRouter = MockRouter();
await tester.pumpWidget(makeTestableWidget(
  child: page,
  auth: MockAuth(),
  database: MockDatabase(),
  router: mockRouter,
));

Finder waiting = find.byType(CircularProgressIndicator);
expect(waiting, findsNothing);

Finder placeholder = find.byType(PlaceholderContent);
expect(placeholder, findsNothing);

Finder item = find.byKey(Key('jobListItem-${job.id}'));
expect(item, findsOneWidget);

await controller.close();
});
```

And here is my widget code:

```
Widget _buildContent(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder<List<Job>>(
  stream: jobsStream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return ListItemsBuilder(
      snapshot: snapshot,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, Job job) {
        return JobListItem(
          key: Key('jobListItem-${job.id}'),
          title: job.jobName, // TODO: This be null?
          onTap: () => _select(context, job),
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
}
```

And the `ListItemsBuilder`:

```
typedef Widget ItemWidgetBuilder<T>(BuildContext context, T item);

class ListItemsBuilder<T> extends StatelessWidget {
  ListItemsBuilder({this.snapshot, this.itemBuilder});
  final AsyncSnapshot<List<T>> snapshot;
  final ItemWidgetBuilder<T> itemBuilder;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // prints "waiting"
    print('${snapshot.connectionState.toString()}');
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      final items = snapshot.data;
      if (items.length > 0) {
        return _buildList(items);
      } else {
        return PlaceholderContent();
      }
    } else if (snapshot.error != null) {
      print('${snapshot.error}');
      return PlaceholderContent(
        title: 'Something went wrong',
        message: 'Can\'t load entries right now',
      );
    } else {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
  }

  Widget _buildList(List<T> items) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: items.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return itemBuilder(context, items[index]);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I tried using a `StreamController.broadcast(sync: true)` instead of a simple `StreamController`, but it didn't make a difference.

Also any additional `pump()` and `pumpAndSettle()` calls don't make a difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

**Solution**

Use `await tester.pump(Duration.zero);`

Full test code:

```
testWidgets('Job item pressed - shows edit job page',
    (WidgetTester tester) async {
  StreamController<List<Job>> controller = StreamController<List<Job>>();

  Job job = Job(id: '0', createdAt: 0, jobName: 'Dart');
  controller.add([job]);

  final page = JobsPage(
    jobsStream: controller.stream,
  );
  MockRouter mockRouter = MockRouter();
  await tester.pumpWidget(makeTestableWidget(
    child: page,
    auth: MockAuth(),
    database: MockDatabase(),
    router: mockRouter,
  ));

  // this will cause the stream to emit the first event
  await tester.pump(Duration.zero);

  Finder waiting = find.byType(CircularProgressIndicator);
  expect(waiting, findsNothing);

  Finder placeholder = find.byType(PlaceholderContent);
  expect(placeholder, findsNothing);

  Finder item = find.byKey(Key('jobListItem-${job.id}'));
  expect(item, findsOneWidget);

  await controller.close();
});
```